# Search functionality is not properly working

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, youtube-api, flutter-dependencies

I have show loading in else condition
if there  search controller contain text it show that card otherwise it show loading in every empty card
and if only one item is present than 13loading showing
and also show loading that i discuss to add space Now instead of space it has loading
Now I want if there  is search controller contain no text then it show one loading but my code show 14(length) loading 
And Also i want the item in arrangement and don't show loading if there is an  item
is present I think you understand very well
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLcOw.jpg)

```
ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              final video = data[index];
                              print("Length is ${snapshot.data!.length}");
                             try {
                               if (_searchController.text
                                   .toString()
                                   .isEmpty) {
                                 return InkWell(
                                   onTap: () {
                                     Navigator.push(
                                       context,
                                       MaterialPageRoute(
                                         builder: (builder) =>
                                             video_detail(
                                               data: video['snippet']["publishTime"],
                                               title: video['snippet']["title"],
                                               videoId: video["id"]["videoId"],
                                               channelTitle: video["snippet"]["channelTitle"],
                                               descrption: video["snippet"]["description"],
                                               thumbnail: video['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                                             ),
                                       ),
                                     );
                                   },
                                   child: Card(
                                     margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                     color: AppColor.grey200,
                                     child: Column(
                                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                           .start,
                                       children: [
                                         Image.network(
                                           video['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                                           width: MediaQuery
                                               .of(context)
                                               .size
                                               .width * 1,
                                         ),
                                         Padding(
                                           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                           child: Column(
                                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                 .start,
                                             children: [
                                               Text(
                                                 video['snippet']['title'],
                                                 style: const TextStyle(
                                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                   fontSize: 18,
                                                 ),
                                               ),
                                             ],
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ],
                                     ),
                                   ),

                                 );
                               }
                               else if (video['snippet']['title']
                                   .toString()
                                   .toLowerCase()
                                   .contains(_searchController.text.toString()
                                   .trim()
                                   .toLowerCase()) ||
                                   video['snippet']['description']
                                       .toString()
                                       .toLowerCase()
                                       .contains(_searchController.text.toString()
                                       .trim()
                                       .toLowerCase())
                               ) {
                                 return Padding(
                                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                   child: Card(
                                     child: ListTile(
                                       leading: Image.network(
                                         video['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                                         width: 50,
                                       ),
                                       title: Text(video['snippet']['title']),
                                       trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                                       onTap: () {
                                         Navigator.push(
                                           context,
                                           MaterialPageRoute(
                                             builder: (builder) =>
                                                 video_detail(
                                                   data: video['snippet']["publishTime"],
                                                   title: video['snippet']["title"],
                                                   videoId: video["id"]["videoId"],
                                                   channelTitle: video["snippet"]["channelTitle"],
                                                   descrption: video["snippet"]["description"],
                                                   thumbnail: video['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                                                 ),
                                           ),
                                         );
                                       },
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 );
                               }
                               else{
                                 return Center(
                                   child: LoadingAnimationWidget.fourRotatingDots(
                                     color: AppColor.grey,
                                     size: 200,
                                   ),
                                 );
                               }
                             }
                             catch(e){
                               print(e);
                             }
                            },
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this loading. What the loading is waiting for? Either you find or not. You should filter the data before list it. You are finding 14 cause you are not filtering the list.

I think a better approach would be something like this. Create a method which filter your data if there's a text in input.

```
List get filteredData {
  final text = _searchController.text;
  if (text.isEmpty) return data;
  return data.where((element) {
    // your condition where data contains text
  }).toList();
}
```

Then, show only the filtered data in your ListView, you could check if filteredData.isEmpty before, so you could show a message like "No video found".

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: filteredData.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
    final video = filteredData[index];
  // ...
)
```